# Most appropriate place to require library in Padrino/Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I'm using "therubyracer" in a model, and I'm requiring at the top of the model as so:

```
require 'v8'
class Thing
  def self.ctx; @@ctx ||= V8::Context.new; end;

  def self.eval(script); ctx.eval(script); end;
end
```

However, I intermittently get:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant Thing::V8: 
/app/thing.rb:3:in `ctx'
```

When testing requests through a local Padrino server, apparently after I modify code in Thing.  This is corrected by restarting the padrino server.  I'm assuming requiring v8 somewhere else would fix this problem, wheres the correct place?

Comment: I'd say you've put the `require` in the right place - near the code that needs it. How are you running the tests?

Comment: Hitting the model from a controller action via POST.  So padrino server is running via padrino s.  Unit tests all work fine, never triggers the error.

Comment: I'd add a `warn` statement in the file so you know when the file has been reloaded.

Comment: , as it'll help you track down what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it might be caused by the Padrino reloader getting confused when it reloads your `thing.rb` file, causing Ruby to look for `V8` in the `Thing` namespace.

Try explicitly specifying `V8` is in the top level using the `::` prefix:

```ruby
def self.ctx; @@ctx ||= ::V8::Context.new; end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it wherever you want if you add it on the Gemfile. Did you added it?

Thanks!